# "Unused" folder with Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to have a folder for unused stuff with Visual Studio Express?

This folder will be listed, but ignored by builder and other IDE components.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You can create one of your own and decide not to use it/ignore it (although i can't image what purpose would this serve).

Comment: For example, I can start developing something that I am not going to use straight away. This may have some errors which prevent the project from being compiled, so I want it to be ignored at the moment. Or, I may have an alternative version of the code (using a different idea) and hesitate which one to use, or just an image or a library which is currently unused, but may be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE ignores any file not part of a project in the solution. You can add the folder under the project if you want. Just make sure anything that is in it, don't select "Include in Project" in the context menu (or select "Exclude from Project" as necessary).

For the IDE to ignore files by default, you will have to copy/paste them into the folder manually. If you use the "Add" context menu, it automatically includes it into the project.

In order to see all files/folders regardless whether they are in the project or not, select "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer. (In fact, I would suggest this is the default via Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Project Settings > Solution Explorer Mode > Show All Files.)

Comment: If I select "Exclude from Project", the folder will no longer be listed. But I want it to be listed, but ignored.

Comment: Thank you, Casey. Maybe this is true for full Visual Studio, but I use Visual Studio Express (so, I corrected my question). If I select "Add New Folder" it just adds is without giving an option not to include in the project. And when I later say "Exclude from Project" it removes the folder from the list.

Comment: @cyanide I would definitely suggest you upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. It is completely free and comparable to the Professional Editions (i.e. better than the Express versions) of older versions. :) P.S. I meant to say "I edited my answer" but did not notice the typo until after the allowed edit time had passed.

Comment: Indeed, this time limitation on editing the comment is really annoying. As far as I remember it appeared just recently, and I can't see any reason behind it. Hopefully, it will go soon :).  As about Community vs Express Editions, each one has advantages and disadvantages. I might try community edition one day.  For now, I will mark your response as an answer, keeping in mind Community edition users :)